# Удаляет ли TreeSet повторения?

Tags: java

Наткнулся на реализацию TreeSet в которой по условию задачи нужно сделать сортировку по возрастанию без повторов и в одном из показных решений это делают просто через TreeSet... Но насколько я помню, TreeSet не удаляет повторения а просто складывает в порядке возрастания... Или нет?

Comment: в сете не могут храниться одинаковые элементы, что именно считать одинаковым зависит от функции equals(). Поэтому да, это решение подойдёт.

Comment: @pavel В `TreeSet` одинаковость зависит не от equals, а от compare/compareTo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все классы, реализующие множества (`Set`) (например, `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, `TreeSet`) могут содержать **только уникальные элементы**.